# rake db:migrate not doing anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dbmigrate

I'm following the onemonthrails tutorial, and I'm in the "New User Signup and Signin" lesson. I followed all the steps correctly, but I'm running into an error :

```
"ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Devise::RegistrationsController#new
```

Could not find table 'users'"

The only thing that was different on my terminal than the teacher's one is the "run db:migrate" that doesn't do anything...

The full error trace gives me this :

```
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:512:in `table_structure'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:387:in `columns'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:93:in `block in prepare_default_proc'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:44:in `yield'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:44:in `columns'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:214:in `columns'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:223:in `columns_hash'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:180:in `subclass_from_attributes?'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:23:in `new'
devise (3.1.2) lib/devise/models/registerable.rb:20:in `new_with_session'
devise (3.1.2) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:92:in `build_resource'
devise (3.1.2) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:7:in `new'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:45:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/Users/pablofaust/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/pablofaust/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/pablofaust/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

What should I do ?

Comment: try add dev env `run db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development`.

Comment: did you mean rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development ?

Comment: it doesn't run anything either...

Answer (score 1):

Clearly your migrate is trying to do something to the `Users` table but it doesn't exist. Try `rake db:migrate VERSION=0` and then `rake db:migrate` again to start fresh*. If you run into an error on the down-rake, you can go into your db and delete the database and re-create it to start fresh*.

If you're still having problems, there must be a typo in your migration file(s).

*Note that 'starting fresh' will trash all the data in your database if there is any.

Comment: What should I delete, precisely ?

Comment: Typically when my migrations are going haywire, I just drop my whole `app_development` database, and then add it back in with the same name, then `rake db:migrate`

Comment: Or just drop all the tables in the db. Or if you want to protect your data, just drop Users and any other table which your migration would create after, and then run `rake db:migrate VERSION=XXX` where XXX is found in the name of your `XXX_create_users.rb` file

Answer (score 0):

Migrate the database as:--

```
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure the database exists

`rake db:create`

Then run the migration which is created by devise

`rake db:migrate`